# btrfs confused about subvolumes

Tags: btrfs, flash-memory, volume

I'm starting out with btrfs on my embedded Linux system.  My system currently has a single SD card used for the rfs.

What I'd like to do is have a way to snapshot both the system files (currently under /) and the home directories (under /home).  Is creating the subvolumes /mnt/root and /mnt/home the way to do this?  Once I have created the subvolumes would I then copy all the files that are currently under / and /home to the new subvolumes to populate them and remove the originals?  Or is it better to populate the new subvolumes with snapshots of the source data?

I would also then want to mount these new subvolumes at bootup time, so not sure how to do that.

Comment: For automatic mounting after boot you should add appropriate entries in `/etc/fstab`. Among others you can check http://askubuntu.com/questions/331233/creating-btrfs-subvolume-like-or-home , https://help.ubuntu.com/community/btrfs and http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/767683-how-to-create-and-manage-btrfs-snapshots-and-rollbacks-on-linux-part-2

Answer (score 2):

There is a command `btrfs subvolume snapshot` for this. If you use it, the new subvolume will be populated with the COW references to the original files. Keep in mind, that subvolume mounted on `/` (usually named as `@`) and on `/home` (usual name: `@home`) are separate subvolumes, so you should apply this command to both.

```
usage: btrfs subvolume snapshot [-r] <source> <dest>|[<dest>/]<name>

    btrfs subvolume snapshot [-r] [-i <qgroupid>] <source> <dest>|[<dest>/]<name>

    Create a snapshot of the subvolume
    Create a writable/readonly snapshot of the subvolume <source> with
    the name <name> in the <dest> directory.  If only <dest> is given,
    the subvolume will be named the basename of <source>.

    -r             create a readonly snapshot
    -i <qgroupid>  add the newly created snapshot to a qgroup. This
                   option can be given multiple times.
```